# XAML Extend style of a control - superclass template is taken instead

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

We have a custom XCombobox with its own style, and a subclass YCombobox with its own style as well (most pseudo).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:XComboBox}">
  <Setter Property="Template"/> <!-- some XCombo template, height e.g. 30 -->
<Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:YComboBox}">
  <Setter Property="Template"/> <!-- some YCombo template, height e.g. 30 -->
<Style>
```

Now, I'm having a panel with multiple comboboxes, XCombo's and YCombo's from which I want to alter the height. Instead of setting the height for each control individually, I thought to use the construction:

```
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type x:XComboBox}">
      <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/> <!-- custom height for all XCombo on this page-->
    <Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type x:YComboBox}">
      <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/> <!-- custom heigth -->
    <Style>
    <x:XCombo />
    <x:XCombo />
    <x:XCombo />
    <x:YCombo />
    <x:YCombo />
    <x:YCombo />
  </Grid.Resources>
```

The custom OnApplyTemplate pointed out that a PART was missing; from which I noticed that adding a local override to YCombo, its template had changed to the XCombo template.

I had also tried to add the basedOn, but without success:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type x:YComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type x:YComboBox}}">
      <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/> <!-- custom heigth-->
    <Style>
```

If anybody has a clue I'd appreciate it.

N.b. I prefer to avoid to setting a style to each combo.

Comment: You realise all your height values are 25? The most specific style to the scope the combo is in should win. I'm not totally clear where all your styles are.

Comment: The original/default height differs from 25, I'm trying to achieve 25